# gcc compilation error at /usr/include/net/if.h in C++

Tags: c++, unix, gcc, compilation, solaris

Im using gcc version 4.4.1, xmake version 2.17.3. I get the following error when compiling.

`

```
In file included from /rtcigp/run/pd/ACE/6.0.7_x86/64Opt/include/ace/os_include/net/os_if.h:28,
from /rtcigp/run/pd/ACE/6.0.7_x86/64Opt/include/ace/OS_NS_sys_socket.h:29,
from /rtcigp/run/pd/ACE/6.0.7_x86/64Opt/include/ace/ACE.inl:8,
from /rtcigp/run/pd/ACE/6.0.7_x86/64Opt/include/ace/ACE.h:886,
from /rtcigp/run/pd/ACE/6.0.7_x86/64Opt/include/ace/String_Base.cpp:6,
from /rtcigp/run/pd/ACE/6.0.7_x86/64Opt/include/ace/String_Base.h:882,
from /rtcigp/run/pd/ACE/6.0.7_x86/64Opt/include/ace/SString.h:23,
from /rtcigp/run/pd/ACE/6.0.7_x86/64Opt/include/tao/CDR.h:61,
from /rtcigp/run/pd/ACE/6.0.7_x86/64Opt/include/tao/UB_String_Argument_T.cpp:7,
from /rtcigp/run/pd/ACE/6.0.7_x86/64Opt/include/tao/UB_String_Argument_T.h:177,
from /rtcigp/run/pd/ACE/6.0.7_x86/64Opt/include/tao/Any_Insert_Policy_T.h:18,
from /rtcigp/run/pd/ACE/6.0.7_x86/64Opt/include/tao/Basic_Arguments.h:25,
from /rtcigp/run/pd/ACE/6.0.7_x86/64Opt/include/tao/IOPC.h:52,
from /rtcigp/run/pd/ACE/6.0.7_x86/64Opt/include/tao/Object.h:23,
from /rtcigp/run/pd/ACE/6.0.7_x86/64Opt/include/TAO/corba.h:39,
from ../../include/processors/chat/ms_chat.h:18,
from ../../include/processors/chat/forging.h:9,
from /home/akilis/ktph/leaf/src/ktph/processors/chat/src/forging.cpp:6:
/usr/include/net/if.h: At global scope:
/usr/include/net/if.h:99: error: template argument required for 'struct map'
```

`

I found a [solution](http://bugzilla.abisource.com/show_bug.cgi?id=13541) to this problem. I included `<net/if.h>` before all other includes as suggested. But it doesnt solve the problem. I still get the same error.

my `../../include/processors/chat/forging.h:9` looks as below

`

```
 9  #include "processors/chat/ms_chat.h"
10  #include <string>
11  // chat
12  #include <vector>
13  #include <gtcpp/mtlock.h>
14  #include <map>
15  //
16  #include "env/GenericMapper.h"
17
18  using namespace std;
```

`

then `/rtcigp/run/pd/ACE/6.0.7_x86/64Opt/include/ace/os_include/net/os_if.h:28` looks as follows

`

```
27  #if !defined (ACE_LACKS_NET_IF_H)
28  #  include /**/ <net/if.h>
29  #  if defined (ACE_HAS_NET_IF_DL_H)
30  #    include /**/ <net/if_dl.h>
31  #  endif /* ACE_HAS_NET_IF_DL_H */
```

`

The peculiar thing is that this code compiles without any fuss in solaris CC. The problem pops out only when I compile with gcc.

Am I missing something here? Should there be some changes made in the code when changing to gcc from CC. Or is this a bug in gcc compiler which has been fixed in the later versions?

Comment: Are you `using std::map` or `using namespace std` or neither?

Comment: Im doing `using      namespace std;`

Comment: Before or after including net/if.h?

Comment: im using `using namespace std;` after `include net/if.h`

Comment: _"But when I include <net/if.h> before all other includes, as suggested, it makes my std map unrecognizable to the compiler."_ Let's focus on _this_ problem. The workaround is valid and works for other people.

Comment: Please share your template code snippet

Comment: @VivekD I modified my question with the exact errors i'm getting and the code snippet